# Limit @OneToMany List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Bom dia Galera! Estou com uns problemas em uma lista que em alguns casos não preciso retornar ela por completo

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="local", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy("dataContagem DESC")
private List<Contagem> contagens;
```

Ja tentei utilizando a validation constraint @Size e @Max.
Estou utilizando Hibernate com a especificação JPA. É possivel realizar esse limit da lista OneToMany na query do JPQL ?

Comment: Não é possível. Use Native Query ou JPQL.

Comment: O ideal era você remover o `EAGER` do `@OneToMany` e fazer o controle do número de resultados manualmente, com uma consulta separada só para pegar Contagem, assim você deixa seu código muito mais flexível. O `EAGER` é um "code smell", evite usar ele, prefira usar o `LAZY`.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei essa resposta que deve atender sua necessidade em no [stackoverflow-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895122/4395789)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="local", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("dataContagem DESC")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@Size(min=1, max=10)
private List<Contagem> contagens;
```

Remova o fetch EAGER pq ele pode causar sobrecarga se for usado com uma lista e tiver muitos registros, procure chamar o `contagens.size();` antes de enviar o objeto, o proxy ativo vai fazer a seleção da lista de `contagens`